# No intermediate denominators growth for holonomic functions?

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, differential-equations, recurrences, holonomy

My question concerns *holonomic* sequences of rational numbers, meaning assignments $a(n) : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}$ fulfilling a linear recurrent relation of the form
$$
a(n+k) = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} p_i(n)a(n+i), \quad n = 1, 2, \ldots,
$$
where $p_i(x) \in \mathbb{Q}(x)$ are rational functions. In other words, the generating function $f(X) := \sum_{n} a(n)X^n \in \mathbb{Q}[[X]]$ and fulfills a linear ODE with polynomial coefficients.

Define $D_n$ to be the least common denominator of the rational numbers $a(1), a(2), \ldots, a(n)$. That is the minimum positive integer such that all $a(i) \in \frac{1}{D_n}\mathbb{Z}$ for $i \leq n$. A generalization (which I have no clue how to establish) of the prime number theorem would be that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\log{D_n}$ converges (possibly to $+\infty$).

**Question.** *If $D_n$ is unbounded, does it grow at least exponentially in $n$?*

Comment: Did you try $k=1,2$?

Comment: @MarkSapir: For $k=1$ it shouldn't be too hard to prove that this dichotomy is indeed true. It is also easy when $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \deg{p_i} \in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: How about $k=2$? It may help to rewrite the recurrence relation in a matrix form and reduce the problem to a problem about eigenvalues of powers of a matrix.

Comment: @MarkSapir: But the $p_i(n)$ need not be constant. What you write applies to the $p_i \equiv \mathrm{const}$ case, i.e. when $f(X) \in \mathbb{Q}(X)$ is rational. Example: if $a(n) = 1/n$, or $f(X) = -\log(1-X)$, we have $D_n = [1,\ldots,n] = e^{n + o(n)}$, by the prime number theorem. I have no idea how to prove the $k=2$ case; rather trying to get a sense if the statement looks plausible in general.

Comment: I did not write that the entries of matrices should be numbers. If $p_i$ are polynomials, the entries should be probably rational functions.